# A group-theoretic lemma in a paper by Ershov and He

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, centralisers

In the proof of Lemma 2.1 in

*Ershov, Mikhail; He, Sue*, [**On finiteness properties of the Johnson filtrations**](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2018-0005),  [ZBL06904638](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06904638),

the authors claim the following (without proof).

*Let $G$ be a finitely generated group, and let $g_1,\ldots,g_k\in G$ be pairwise commuting elements, such that the union of the centralizers $S:=\bigcup_{i=1}^k\mathrm{Cent}_G(g_i)$ generates $G$. Then it is possible to find a finite generating set for $G$ contained in $S$.*

I can't see why this should be true in general, but I don't have any counter-example either. Can anybody help me?

Comment: This only needs the fact that $G$ is finitely generated and $S$ is a generating set.  If $T$ is a finite generating set for $G$, then since $S$ is another generating set each $t$ in $T$ can be written as a word in $S$.  Let $S’$ contain the letters that appear in such words as $t$ ranges over $T$.  Then $S’$ is a finite generating set.

Comment: Thanks, so simple!

Comment: It's always better to post answers as answers (not as comments) so that the question doesn't remain unanswered in the UI; also for better visibility of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is @AndyPutman's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435523/a-group-theoretic-lemma-in-a-paper-by-ershov-and-he#comment1122032_435523) as an answer (so that it can be accepted), made CW to avoid reputation.  If @AndyPutman prefers to post the answer, then I will delete this.

> This only needs the fact that $G$ is finitely generated and $S$ is a generating set.  If $T$ is a finite generating set for $G$, then since $S$ is another generating set each $t$ in $T$ can be written as a word in $S$.  Let $S'$ contain the letters that appear in such words as $t$ ranges over $T$.  Then $S'$ is a finite generating set.

Comment: This is fine with me.